# Are there any good server hosting services for large subversion repos?

Tags: svn, version-control, hosting, large-files, game-development

A small team, that I am a part of, is working on a game, and we have encountered a roadblock when it comes to version control. The source code is currently hosted  on Github as a temporary solution, however when art, sound and other assets start piling up this will most certainly be problematic, as git does not handle large binary files well. Github provides options for setting up a repository which is managed with subversion, instead of git, however the pricing is a bit steep.
My question is therefore: **Are there any good server hosting services with a reasonable price that is suited for version control of large binary files with Subversion?**

Comment: What about hosting your own server on MS Azure or AWS Windows VM or on your own server?

Comment: Have you heard of git lfs (large file support)?